# xsel and xclip hang

Tags: x11, clipboard, xclip, xsel

My objective is to make a text on my remote machine (CentOS 7.2) available to seamlessly paste on my local machine (OS X 10.12.2) with the standard ⌘V shortcut.  My setup connects to the remote machine with `ssh -Y` and then attaches to tmux (or creates a new session if non-existent).  When I run either `echo "test" | xsel -ib` or `echo "test" | xclip` it hangs.  The `$DISPLAY` variable is `localhost:10.0`.  If I exit tmux the `$DISPLAY` variable seems to be null and I get a can't open display error.

Answer (score 0):

MacOS does not use XOrg Server, but Quartz graphics stack, or some other crap (it is some years I worked with macs daily).

You either want to run XOrg on Mac OS (this used to be possible), or learn how to use mac native pbcopy(1) and pbpaste(1) commands.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool to handle this type problem using a Gitlab snippet some while a go. It might work for your use case.

See https://github.com/bradwood/glsnip